# Power BI not refreshing

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, office365

I am no Database administrator or data scientist, but in my campany we needed to have  a BI with several metrics so I have built a PowerBI Dataset (semantic model) stored in a Power BI Premium per user workspace. The data is retrieved via a PowerBI Gateway.

The model is composed of 25 tables. The Fact table is central and all other tables are a way of filtering the Fact table.

Below the description of the model and the number of rows in the SQL :

[image: Model]

Incremental Update is enabled on one of the table (the biggest, Facts). Everyday an external .net process publish about 2 millions rows in the Facts table. Other tables may changes but globally remain the same.

The Dataset definition is very simple, there's no transformation of the data retrieved, it is the SQL Server table directly.

It was working but now I can't get the sync to work.

In the PowerBI portal I had timeout error messages, so I tried to understand where was the timeout. I reduce the history on the SQL (it was 300M rows in Facts), tried to profile the O365 Analysis Services and my SQL Server to understand from where the timeout was coming (unfortunately Analysis logs was not clear to me)

It seems that retrieving the 2M rows from the SQL to the PowerBI Gateway takes about 2 minutes. Logs in the gateway indicates that the content was streamed to O365 in about 2 minutes also.

I tried to sync partition manually from SQL Server Management Studio connected directly to Analysis Services. The error persists when trying to perform a Full and even with DataOnly, I still get errors.

Recently the error message changed. It is now this one :

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error retumed: The operation was throttled by the Power BI Premium because of insufficient memory. Please try again later.

I have checked the size of the DataSet in O365, and it is about 4.8Gb. The limit size is 100Gb in the description of the PowerBI Premium per user.

I really don't understand why it is no longer working, and why I have now errors I did not had before.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks